# Array of time periods with start and end date by range

Tags: php, arrays, datetime, codeigniter-3

I want to generate a table with values based on an array of time intervals that shows the start and end dates of each period. The periods can be in fixed intervals, example (P1D, P1M, etc).

I already have a function that generates the closed (past) periods, but I can not find a way to do it with future dates.

This is the function:

```
function interval($start, $interval, $break = 0)
{
    $result = array();

    $today = date("Y-m-d");
    if ($break == 0) {
        if ($today < $start) $break = 1;
    }

    $date = new DateTime($start);
    $interval = new DateInterval($interval);

    $f1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($start));

    $x = TRUE;
    if ($break == 0) {
        do {
            $date->add($interval);
            $f2 = $date->format('Y-m-d');
            $result[] = array(
                'begin' => $f1,
                'end'    => $f2
            );
            $x = ($f1 <= $today && $f2 >= $today) ? TRUE : FALSE;
            $f1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 day', strtotime($f2)));

        } while (!$x);

    } else {

        for ($n = 1; $n <= $break; $n++) {
            $date->add($interval);
            $f2 = $date->format('Y-m-d');
            $result[] = array(
                'begin' => $f1,
                'end'    => $f2
            );
            $f1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 day', strtotime($f2)));
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

For use simply call to function:

```
print_r(interval('2019-01-01', 'P1M'));
```

And result this:

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [begin] => 2019-01-01
            [end] => 2019-02-01
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [begin] => 2019-02-02
            [end] => 2019-03-01
        )

)
```

I am looking to do the same but with future periods, for example, from 01-01-2019 to 01-01-2023 in 1-month intervals (P1M).

**Update**

The answer of @dWinder is the closest thing to the solution I looking for without having to travel in time =), and it works very well with monthly and annual intervals, but with shorter periods (P15D, P1W, P1D), the script presents problems that I can not identify.

I updated the function that you published so that it ran through the array correctly and stayed like this:

```
function interval($start, $interval, $maxPeriods = 100, $end = NULL) {
    $result = array();
    //$today = date("Y-m-d"); ** Variable not used, disable it **
    $date = new DateTime($start);
    $interval = new DateInterval($interval);

    $f1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($start));
    do {
        $date->add($interval);
        $f2 = $date->format('Y-m-d');
        $result[] = array( 'begin' => $f1, 'end' => $f2);
        if ($end <> NULL && $end == $f2) break; // if over the end date stop the loop
        $f1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 day', strtotime($f2)));

    } while (++$maxPeriods); // I changed -- to ++ to avoid stopping the loop
    return $result;
}
```

The updated function is used in this way:

```
print_r(interval('2019-01-01', 'P1M', NULL, '2023-01-01'));
```

And the results:

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [begin] => 2019-01-01
            [end] => 2019-02-01
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [begin] => 2019-02-02
            [end] => 2019-03-01
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [begin] => 2019-03-02
            [end] => 2019-04-01
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [begin] => 2019-04-02
            [end] => 2019-05-01
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [begin] => 2019-05-02
            [end] => 2019-06-01
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [begin] => 2019-06-02
            [end] => 2019-07-01
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [begin] => 2019-07-02
            [end] => 2019-08-01
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [begin] => 2019-08-02
            [end] => 2019-09-01
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [begin] => 2019-09-02
            [end] => 2019-10-01
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [begin] => 2019-10-02
            [end] => 2019-11-01
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [begin] => 2019-11-02
            [end] => 2019-12-01
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [begin] => 2019-12-02
            [end] => 2020-01-01
        )
)...
```

Comment: Did my post helped you?

Comment: @dWinder you answer is the closest thing to the solution that I looking for, thanks!

Comment: Why did you changed the "<" in line`if ($end <> NULL && $end < $f2) break;` to "="? And if you do `while (++$maxPeriods);` then the max value will not work - what do you want to achieve? and more important - what problem do you have with shorter periods?

Comment: @dWinder I change "<" to "==" for avoid the array create an additional period than the end date. In the example on  question, the last value of end date with "<" are : 2023-02-01, but with "==" the end date are: 2023-01-01 that is espected result. With this, only change the intervals and working fine. When I try to run with shorter intervals (P1D is a bad result), (P1W, P15D the script not responding).

Comment: I guess P1W and P15D will be infinity loop when using `==` because it may hop over the exact end date - I recommend using `<` and after the function remove the last element

Comment: @dWinder I tried with adding this condition ` if(in_array($interval, array('P1D', 'P15D', 'P1W'))){ if ($end <> NULL && $end < $f2) break; } else { if ($end <> NULL && $end == $f2) break; } ` and remove last key in this same case, but result an infinite loop.

Comment: I ran that: `print_r(interval('2019-01-01', 'P1D', 10000000, '2023-01-01'));` on my original code and it worked fine. Please edit the question with you code (or open a new question) so we can try find your issue. please avoid the `if` of small interval and just remove last element at the end of the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better solution will be sending "end" argument and check it (in additional to the "maxPeriods"

Consider the follow (notice the comment in the code):

```
function interval($start, $interval, $maxPeriods = 100, $end = null) {
    $result = array();
    $today = date("Y-m-d");
    $date = new DateTime($start);
    $interval = new DateInterval($interval);

    $f1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($start));
    do {
            $date->add($interval);
            $f2 = $date->format('Y-m-d');
            $result[] = array( 'begin' => $f1, 'end' => $f2);
            if ($end && $end < $f2) break; // if over the end date stop the loop
            $f1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 day', strtotime($f2)));

    } while (--$maxPeriods); //till you get max elements
    return $result;
}
```

Now call it with

```
print_r(interval('2019-01-01', 'P1M', 48));
//or
print_r(interval('2019-01-01', 'P1M', null, "2023-01-01"));
```

Notice that the first role encounter with break the loop (end date or max elements)

Answer (score 0):

A time machine would help :) If the program correctly calculates past periods, then if it "thought" today was '2023-01-01' (give or take), it would correctly calculate the past periods. Can you add `$end` argument, default to today?